# Align position of <apex:pageMessages> tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I would like to center the error message displayed via `<apex:PageMessages>` however it is not responding to `div`/`css` tags such as `div align="center"` or `text-align: center;` - does anyone know how we can center `<apex:pageMessages>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apex:pageMessages element doesn't appear to want to appear inside a div (it gets "kicked out" into its own area), so some trickery is required.

The only reasonable solution I've found so far is to modify the inner CSS rules:

```
<style>
.message {
    text-align: center;
}
.messageTable {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

The first aligns the text within the "message" area, the second makes the table have a 100% width (by default, it's "auto").

Comment: Thanks, I found that `margin-left` also worked